# Symfony3 login without redirect

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

Been searching the web for an answer but found none. Maybe I'm not asking google the right question.

I want to authenticate the user without the "/login" redirect. Basically if I access /admin (or /user or something that requires login) I want to show the login form for without being redirected to "/login".

Also if the session dies if the user is i want to show the login form without being redirect (though this part is, I think, [covered](https://blog.intelligentbee.com/2015/08/25/how-to-fix-symfony2-ajax-login-redirect/)).

Any material or documentation I can read would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: dont understand the downvotes, but sure...

Answer (score 2):

Without page reloading, you need to use JavaScript for logging the users. Symfony 3.3 and later provide JSON endpoint for logging users via JS. Check this [link](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-json-authentication).

Comment: I'll give the security doc more read. Thanks for the link its a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Found what i needed in [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#use-forward):

> use_forward
>
> type: boolean default: false
>
> If you'd like the user to be forwarded to the login form instead of being redirected, set this option to true.

There is, currently, an example there too.

Edit: In combination with the *use_referer* parameter (as true) is pretty much what I was looking for.